# How to prevent data changes in a child from affecting it's parent? Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript

So I have an Angular app in which I am using several children components to build d3 graphs for the parent page, 'site'.

I make the request to the service on the parent component, which will return a list of site objects containing all the data to graph for each. I pass that data to the d3 graph components.

**My issue is:** When I restructure data in a child component, why does it appear to overwrite data/include these changes from the original request (when I console.log on the parent)? I am not using any @Output decorators.

I need data in a parent to **not** be affected by its children... I'm not sure why it's happening! Please help if you can, and let me know if I can clarify anything. Thank you!

Here's what my files look like:

**sites.component.ts:**
I make a request to the service to recieve back a list of all of my sites and the random data that goes with them. I store them in 'sites'

```
import { Component, Inject, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { AuthService } from "../services/auth.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sitelist',
  templateUrl: './sitelist.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sitelist.component.css']
})
export class SitelistComponent implements OnInit {
  sites;
  constructor( private _dataService: DataService, private http: Http,  public authService: AuthService ) {
  }
ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.getSites()
    .map((res:Response) => (
       res.json() 
     ))
    .subscribe(data => {
       console.log(data)
       this.sites = data
       console.log(this.sites)
    })
  }
}
```

**sites.component.html**
I loop through each site to render the 'summary' component for each as a table row, passing 'site' data to each

```
<table class="responsive-table striped">
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let site of sites">
        <app-summary [site]="site"></app-summary>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Summary.component.ts**
For each site, I render the summary component and accept one site's worth of data through '@Input() site;' I restructure it so that when I send it to the children (d3 graph components) it's already readable to the graphs. I store it in 'site_info'

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import { AuthService } from "../services/auth.service"; 
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-summary',
  templateUrl: './summary.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./summary.component.css'],

})
export class SummaryComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  @Input() site;

constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,private _dataService: DataService, private http: Http, public authService: AuthService, private router:Router ) {}
date: Date;
dates: any;
value: Number;
eachobj: any;
data: any;
average: any;
site_info: any;

ngAfterViewInit(){

}
ngOnInit() {

this.data = this.site
console.log(this.site)

this.dates = Object.keys(this.data.historical_data)
this.site_info = Object.keys(this.data.historical_data).map(key=>this.data.historical_data[key])

this.site_info = this.site_info.map((obj, i) => {
  if (!obj) {
    return {
      id: this.site.id,
      name: this.site.name,
      date: this.dates[i]};
  }
  obj.id = this.site.id,
  obj.name = this.site.name,
  obj.date = this.dates[i];
  return obj;
 });
}
```

**summary.component.html**
Here is where I send the site_info data to more children components to graph it. These are essentially grandchildren components to the 'site.component.ts' file.

```
 <td id="td3">
   <app-precipitation [site1]="site_info"></app-precipitation>
</td>
<td id="td4">
   <app-volume [site1]="site_info"></app-volume>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way to solve it is to copy the object:

```
export class SitelistComponent implements OnInit {
sites;
original;

constructor(){
}   
ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.getSites()
    .map((res:Response) => (
       res.json() 
     ))
    .subscribe(data => {
       console.log(data)
       const copies = [];
       for(let item of data) {
         copy = this.copy(item);
         copies.push(copy);
       }
       this.original = data;
       this.sites = copies;
       console.log(this.sites)
    })
  }
}

copy(object: any):any{
 return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try to make a copy of `site` in `ngOnInit`:

```
this.data = Object.assign({}, this.site);
```

Comment: Does this need to go in the ngOnInit in my parent component, before I pass it down? Or in the child component once I receive it from the parent?

Comment: I would try one and then other, see if/what that works for you :)